# Docker runs of "pip install" and "npm install" on same container overwriting each other

Tags: docker, npm, pip, docker-compose

In my docker container, I'm trying to install several packages with pip along with installing Bower via npm.  It seems however that whichever of pip or npm run first, the other's contents in /usr/local/bin are overwritten (specifically, gunicorn is missing with the below Dockerfile, or Bower is missing if I swap the order of my `FROM..RUN` blocks).

Is this the expected behavior of Docker, and if so, how can I go about installing both my pip packages and Bower into the same directory, /usr/local/bin?

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.4.3
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD ./requirements/ /code/requirements/
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements/docker.txt
ADD ./ /code/

FROM node:0.12.7
RUN npm install bower
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: .
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    #-redis:redis
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000 --reload

webstatic:
  restart: always
  build: .
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  command: bash -c "/code/manage.py bower install && /code/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

nginx:
  restart: always
  #build: ./config/nginx
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
    - config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  volumes_from:
    - webstatic
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

**Update:** I went ahead and cross-posted this as a [docker-compose issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1884) since it's unclear if there is an actual bug or if my configuration is a problem. I'll keep both posts updated, but do post in either if you have an idea of what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: Is it a typo, or there is a space on `ADD . /requirements /code/requirements/` ?

Comment: Typo; good catch. I'll update my post. I was wondering why pip keep installing with each "build". Unfortunately, still same problem with npm/pip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use multiple `FROM` commands in Dockerfile and you cannot create image from 2 different base images. So if you need node and python in the same image you could either add node to python image or add python to node image.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I have a better understanding of Docker and Compose now. Your post also lead me to this [other (closed) issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3378) where someone else has the same use-case, and others suggest a few workarounds.